# Is it possible to open the subreport with onclick event in pentaho?

Tags: onclick, pentaho, subreport

I have a master report which has several columns, A, B and C.

When a user clicks on any data in B, using the `onclick` event, a subreport has to open showing some detailed data regarding the selected value.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to create that behavior through the report designer. In order to create that kind of behavior you are describing, you will need to learn about Mondrian (in order to create Cubes for your data) and the Dashboard Editor (in order to create a view to replicate your desired behavior using data from the Cubes).

Answer (score 0):

... you can however link to a separate report and show that report.

If you are more technically versed you can achive that within the same report as well, but it is more complex. Parametrize the visibility of your subreport and link to the current report with a changed parameter value for that subreport's visibility. Clicking that link will then re-generate the report with the new parameter set, and you can use a formula function on the subreport to trigger its visibility.

Answer (score 0):

```
="javascript:window.open('/page.jsp?Parameter1="&URLENCODE([param1])&"&outputType=text/html&paginate=true')"
```

use this in on click attribute in report designer it may will help you